# Why can't a mutableStateOf based data class update UI automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The `var myData= mutableStateOf(MyData())` is based a data class, I think the UI component associated with it can be updated automatically when it changed.

I run the following code, I hope the text of `Currect` and `Max` on the UI can be updated automatically after I click "Start" button, but UI doesn't update, why?

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {

    var temp= mutableStateOf(0)

    data class MyData(
        var current:Int=1,
        var max:Int=100
    ) 

    var myData= mutableStateOf(MyData())

    private var myJob: Job?=null

    private fun soundDbFlow(period: Long=100) = flow {
        while (true) {
            val data =(0..1000).random()
            emit(data)
            delay(period)
        }
    }

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            soundDbFlow().collect {setMyData(it)}
        }
    }

    fun setMyData(input: Int) {
        temp.value=input    //Only for test

        myData.value.current = input
        if (input > myData.value.max) {
            myData.value.max = input
        }

       //myData.value= MyData(myData.value.current, myData.value.max)               Doesn't work
       //myData = mutableStateOf(MyData(myData.value.current, myData.value.max) )  Doesn't work
   }
}


@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {

    var myData = handleMeter.myData

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "Current ${myData.value.current}")
        Text(text = "Max ${myData.value.max}")

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
            onClick = { handleMeter.calCurrentAsynNew() }
        ) {
            Text("Start")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Naively, it seems to me that myData is never actually changing. Its properties are changing. I would try creating a new instance of it an replacing myData with that new instance. Also remember to use neverEqualPolicy inside of mutableStateOf

Comment: Thanks! What does the `use neverEqualPolicy inside of mutableStateOf ` mean? would you please give me same sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update the value of `myData` state directly for your composables to recompose instead of updating its properties. Also you can use Kotlin delegates to help clean up the code a little bit by getting rid of using `.value` all the time.

```kotlin
data class MyData(
    val current: Int = 1, // Use val instead of var
    val max: Int = 100
)

var myData by mutableStateOf(MyData())

fun setMyData(input: Int) {
    myData = myData.copy(current = input)
    if (input > myData.max) {
        myData = myData.copy(max = input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code `myData = myData.copy(current = input)` doesn't work .

Comment: Does it show a syntax error or is it that the UI isn't updating?

Comment: Unresolved reference: copy

Comment: myData is mutableStateOf

Comment: Use `by` as I have shown in my answer. `var myData by mutableStateOf(MyData())`

Comment: Type 'MutableState<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(HandleMeter, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

Comment: Thanks! but `var myData by mutableStateOf(MyData()) ` is wrong

Comment: You need to import the getters and setters. `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` and `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue`